# RecyclerView With Scroll Bar

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a simple scroll bar to my `RecyclerView`. I have found two suggestions on how to do this, but neither have given me results. These suggestions are [setting the orientation of the `LayoutManager` to `VERTICAL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419093/5115932) and/or [adding the `android:scrollbars="vertical"` attribute to the `RecyclerView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828988/5115932). The first method does not show a scroll bar, and the second crashes the application, with a `NullPointerException`:

```
12-14 16:39:09.392 31768-31768/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.app, PID: 31768
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1654)
            at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:13924)
            at android.view.View.onDrawForeground(View.java:17657)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3097)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my code for initializing the `RecyclerView`, which works fine as long as I do not have the attribute `android:scrollbars="vertical"`, but does not show a scroll bar:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerDecoration(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(dataset));
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a simpler way to get scroll bars for a `RecyclerView`?

---

This is the XML, just a simple `RecyclerView` in a `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--android:scrollbars="vertical"-->
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the xml?

Comment: @inner_class7 Added after the break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, though still not the result I was hoping for. Turns out it was because I was initializing the `RecyclerView` after `onCreate()`, therefore the content view would skip the `RecyclerView` because there is no adapter attached. Then when the `RecyclerView` tries to call `LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()`, because of the attribute `android:scrollbars="vertical"`, it gets a `NullPointerException` because there is no `LayoutManager` attached.

The solution is to initialize the `RecyclerView` in `onCreate()` with a null `Adapter`, then swap the `Adapter` when I receive the data. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecycler.addItemDecoration(new DividerDecoration(this));
    mRecycler.addAdapter(new MyAdapter(null));

    new MyTask(this).execute;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Data> dataset) {
    mRecycler.swapAdapter(new MyAdapter(dataset), false);
}
```

This enables the scrollbar set with `android:scrollbars="vertical"`, but I was hoping for a persistent scrollbar that the user can interact with, not just a visual indicator.

Comment: Thanks - for me this works with just putting the "setLayoutManager" in the Create. Everything else is unnecessary